# How to validate a List of Guid using FluentValidation

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I am trying to validate a List of Guid using Fluent Validation.
My Ids list should have at least one Guid Id. I did some research and found similar questions answered, and the closest I came to a solution was implementing it like below, but it still doesn't work. When I make a request even if I send the List of Ids with values, it gives me the error message that the Value cannot be null. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public class Data
    {
        public List<Guid> Ids{ get; set; }
    }

    public class DataValidator : AbstractValidator<Data>
    {
        public DataValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(d => d.Ids).SetCollectionValidator(new GuidValidator());
        }
    }

    public class GuidValidator : AbstractValidator<Guid>
    {
        public GuidValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x).NotNull().NotEmpty();
        }
    }
```

I have tried this validator as well but it didn't work:

```
    public class DataValidator : AbstractValidator<Data>
    {
        public DataValidator()
        {
            RuleForEach(d => d.Ids).NotNull().NotEmpty();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just chain validators:

```
public class DataValidator : AbstractValidator<Data>
    {
        public DataValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(d => d.Ids)
                .NotNull() //validates whether Ids collection is null
                .NotEmpty() //validates whether Ids collection is empty
                .SetCollectionValidator(new GuidValidator()); //validates each element inside Ids collection using GuidValidator
        }
    }
```

Also, since `Guid` is a struct, you don't have to use `NotNull()` validation inside `GuidValidator`:

```
public class GuidValidator : AbstractValidator<Guid>
    {
        public GuidValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x).NotEmpty();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what about the Guid.Empty case?

Comment: @BozoJoe `GuidValidator` checks if guid is empty

Comment: `NotEmpty()` also checks if input is not null.